# How to check/uncheck menu item and keep windows on top

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am writing a C# web application where I have a menu strip with an option to keep windows always on top. The name of it is `alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem` and during page load I keep it checked because I start with the form being on top:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
}
```

I then have the following code to allow the user to select and change it based on the condition of the menu item:

```
private void alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TRUE - SETTING TO FALSE");
            alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            this.TopMost = false;
        }
        if (alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FALSE - SETTING TO TRUE");
            alwaysOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
            this.TopMost = true;
        }
        }
```

When it's commented out, If I go through the menu option, clicking it doesn't uncheck it and then clicking it again doesn't check it. It always remains checked.

The `MessageBox` displays both prompt no matter what I choose.

How can I fix the following:

- **Change check to uncheck and uncheck to check based on the current state?**
- **Also, make the form TopMost based on the selection?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second `if` statement to an `else if`, because now it will change it to `Checked = true`, then in the second check (which equals to true), it'll switch it back to `Checked = false`